# If $y=-e^x\cos2x$, show that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=5e^x\sin(2x+\tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{4}))$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $y=-e^x\cos2x$, show that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=5e^x\sin(2x+\alpha)$ where $\alpha=\tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$.

I've managed to figure out that

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^x(4\sin2x+3\cos2x)
$$

But I'm not sure how I can massage it into the form above. Wolfram Alpha lists it as an alternative form but doesn't show how you get there - what do I need to do and which trig identities are relevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4\sin2x+3\cos2x=5(\frac{4}{5}\sin2x+\frac{3}{5}\cos2x)$

Note we want $\frac{4}{5}\sin2x+\frac{3}{5}\cos2x=\sin(2x+\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$.

By compound angle formula, we know $$\sin(2x+\alpha)=\sin2x\cos(\alpha)+\cos2x\sin(\alpha)$$
So in order to fulfill the requirement, we only need to set $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{4}{5},\sin(\alpha)=\frac{3}{5}$$
Such $\alpha$ exists.
Hence $5(\frac{4}{5}\sin2x+\frac{3}{5}\cos2x)=5\sin(2x+\alpha)$ with $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{4}{5},\sin(\alpha)=\frac{3}{5}$, that is $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: How did you get from $5(\frac{4}{5}\sin2x+\frac{3}{5}\cos2x)$ to $5\sin(2x+\alpha)$?

Comment: @hohner I have added more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use $4=5\cos\alpha$, $3=5\sin\alpha$, then use the trigonometric formula for $sin(a+b)$.

Answer (score 0):

use the $a\sin(2x)+b\cos(2x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(2x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(2x)\right)$
and set $\cos(\phi)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\sin(\phi)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$